# Famoc & KNOX on Samsung XCover 3

Tags: samsung, security

I have a problem, I have a phone with Famoc & KNOX enterprise security applications. I was able to root the device with Odin, I've installed twrp-2.8.7.0 & SuperSu.

I've removed this Famoc application, but it seems there's still something wrong, since it can't connect to the Internet at least using UI interface.

I've connected the device to the ADB Android debugging console via USB cable, I can execute commands as an admin (using SU privilege), I can ping whatever server I want and it seems the Internet connection works fine using shell, but when I try to connect to the Internet with Chrome (or anything else) on the phone itself - it doesn't work.

Now my question is, what else can block an Internet access from the phone itself, how to check it (any apps?) or how to enable it? I need some pointers. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

iptables flush did the job, now I need to find out where does it keep those settings ;)

Comment: Care to elaborate your answer to explain in detail please ?